# How to add request options in Angular 2?

Tags: autocomplete, angular2-directives, request-headers

I am trying to implement `Auto search` in Angular 2. I am trying to get data from API to populate in suggestion list. My API accepts headers with token. Below is a sample url:

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: USERNAME PASSWORD' 'https://apsapi.azurewebsites.net/api/searchusers?searchstring=anil'
```

I am using npm ng2-completer plugin. This is my API Call:

```
 constructor(private completerService: CompleterService, private translationService: AppTranslationService, private alertService: AlertService, private useronboardService: UserOnboard) 
    {
           let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers() });
options.headers.set("Authorization",'Bearer0l4B9VpOnJMBzxMee8SQdU8pFW_L8wBAyQ');
        let url = "https://arsapi.azurewebsites.net/api/searchusers?searchstring="
        this.dataService = completerService.remote(url, 'userName', 'userName');
        this.dataService.requestOptions(options);
    }
```

I do not see any header attached in request. Below is image.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV4ny.png) 
Above piece of code results in error and it tells: `(method)RemoteData.requestoptions(requestOptions:any):void (TS)Expected 1 arguments but got 2`.

Can someone help me to add header in the above code?

Comment: Could you please add the specific error message?

Comment: Thanks you. i followed https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-completer and in last they have given requestOptions. I am trying to implement this.

Comment: The entire line is coming in red and it says me (method)RemoteData.requestoptions(requestOptions:any):void  (TS)Expected 1 arguments but got 2